# Why image is not in UIButton, when using that code?

Tags: ios, swift, session

Why image is not in UIButton, when using that code ?
I have an image URL to use that image in my app.

```
//Show Image from URL
    let url = URL(string:"https://static.pexels.com/p…/247932/pexels-photo-247932.jpeg")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if (error == nil) && (data != nil) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let img = UIImage(data: data!)
                print(img!)
                self.otlBtnTakeImage.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to use and show the image in UIButton.

```
let url = URL(string:"https://static.pexels.com/photos/247932/pexels-photo-247932.jpeg")
                let session = URLSession.shared
                session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                    if (error == nil) && (data != nil) {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let img = UIImage(data: data!)
                            print(img!)
                            self.otlBtnTakeImage.setImage(img, for: .normal)
                        }
                    }
                }).resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set image like this

```
button.setImage(img, for: .normal) // To set image with title.
button.setBackgroundImage(img, for: .normal) // set btn background image.
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to make the same code run asynchronously, not blocking the UI, is by using GCD:

```
let url = URL(string: image.url)
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.otlBtnTakeImage.setImage = UIImage(data: data!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Show Image from URL
let url = URL(string:"https://static.pexels.com/p…/247932/pexels-photo-247932.jpeg")
let session = URLSession.shared
session.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    if (error == nil) && (data != nil) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let img = UIImage(data: data!)
            print(img!)
            self.otlBtnTakeImage.setImage(img, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}).resume()
```

The above changes may solve your issue and a display image in the button

Answer (score 0):

You can set image of UIButton like this.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "imagename.png")
yourButton.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
yourButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```